# segmentation fault

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, magento2.3, magento2.3.0

Just updated from M2.2.7 to M2.3.0.

And now have next trouble:

```
 git:(update-to-2.3.0) ✗bin/magento setup:di:compile 
Compilation was started.Repositories code generation...
1/7 [====>-----------------------]  14% < 1 sec 68.0 MiB[1]    37938 segmentation fault  bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

have some ideas what is it?

Answer (score 1):

Try this [Workaround](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/trouble/tshoot_segfault.html), run the below command as a Magento file system owner.

> ulimit -s 65536

You can change this to a larger value if needed. If this not solved the issue, please follow the below.

`segmentation fault` error happening most of the time due to code issue, please make sure your upgrade completed correctly or not, just upgrade one more time and checked it again.